# Programmatically UITableView using swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create a simple tableView programmatically using swift, so I wrote this code on  "AppDelegate.swift" :

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var tvc :TableViewController = TableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.window!.rootViewController = tvc

    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
    }
```

Basically I added the TableViewController creation and added to the window. And this is the TableViewController code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
 }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// #pragma mark - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = "Hello World"

    return cell
}
```

}

So, when I try to run the code I receive this message:

> Xcode6Projects/TableSwift/TableSwift/TableViewController.swift: 12: 12: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'TableSwift.TableViewController'

The error occurs when the compiler is executing the

> super.init(style: style)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Try to add/override the init(nibName:bundle:) method in your class.

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**In Xcode 6 Beta 4**

Removing

```
init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
}
```

will do the trick. This is caused by different initializer behavior between Obj-C and Swift. You have created a designated initializer. If you remove it, all initializers will be inherited.

The root cause is probably in `-[UITableViewController initWithStyle:]` which calls

```
[self initWithNibName:bundle:]
```

I actually think this might be a bug in the way Obj-C classes are converted to Swift classes.

Comment: I had to adjust other things in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but now it's working. Thanks Sulthan !

Comment: What did you adjust? I assume you should be using 'tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier")' because you are not using xib's for cells are you?

Comment: This has been finally fixed in Swift 2, as of XCode 7.0 beta (7A120f). One can use super.init(style: style) directly now…

Answer (score 10):

Instead of

```
init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
}
```

you might find this handy:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(style: .Plain)
    title = "Plain Table"
}
```

Then, you can just call `TableViewController()` to initialize.

Comment: In Xcode 6 beta 5, you can no longer declare a no-argument convenience initializer in this case. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139494/how-to-subclass-uitableviewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: Been looking for this for an hour now. Thank you so much!! Works on Xcode 7.0 & Swift 2.0

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as writing a function

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")

    cell.text = self.Myarray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = "DummyData #\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"123.png")
    return cell
}
```

Comment: cell.text is deprecated and unavailable:
`'text' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift`

Answer (score 1):

**Cell Function Use:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kLCellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
    if !cell {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style:.Default, reuseIdentifier: kLCellIdentifier)
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.textLabel.text = arrData[indexPath.row]
    cell.image = UIImage(named: "\(arrImage[indexPath.row])")   
    cell.accessoryType  = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailDisclosureButton
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}
```