# Required Constructor for UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a ViewController which is a subclass UIViewController. I have some properties which are defined nullable as shown below:

```
  // CloudKit 
    let container :CKContainer?
    let publicDB :CKDatabase?
```

Now, I initialize it using the init constructor method and Xcode complains that I also need to override the initWithCoder constructor which in my opinion feels kind of unnecessary.

```
 init() {

        container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        publicDB = container!.publicCloudDatabase

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        publicDB = container!.publicCloudDatabase

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

I end up with lot of duplicate initialization code for container and publicDB as you can see above.

Is there a better way of doing the same as I have done?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a method called `setup` or something similar and shift these two lines

```
container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
publicDB = container!.publicCloudDatabase
```

in that method. Then, in your different `init` methods, just call `self.setup()`.

---

*Edit*

As a workaround to this problem, you could also make your `container` and `publicDB` variables optional (which they already are) and then set them up in `viewDidLoad`. That way, you will not have to write any `init()` methods at all.

Comment: Absolutely! I can do that but that is just moving the setup call to different initializers. Why do I even need a initWithCoder? It is marked with required but why it cannot just call the base/super implementation itself.

Comment: The thing with Swift is that if you override the `init` method of your superclass, you will also need to override the `initWithCoder:` initializer. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class) question.