# Missing Argument for parameter ‘coder’ in call

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have coded a custom UIButton as :

```
 class AccountOpeningButton: UIButton {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        ......
   }
}
```

I am able to instantiate this Class successfully using my Storyboard.
Now, i made a UIView & want to add this button in my UIView as :

```
var customView:UIView = UIView()
customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 250)
.....
let fromDateBtn:UIButton = AccountOpeningButton()//Error comes here as  : Missing Argument for parameter ‘coder’ in call
customView.addSubview(fromDateBtn)
```

So please help in in reusing this code dynamically also.

P.S. : I referred http://napora.org/nscoder-and-swift-initialization/
[Fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(coder:)' for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class)
[Class does not implement its superclass's required members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126295/swift-class-does-not-implement-its-superclasss-required-members)
But didn't succeed.

=======================================================================
**TRIED**

```
let fromDateBtn:UIButton = UIButton() as! AccountOpeningButton
```

This throws CastException *Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' to '.AccountOpeningButton'*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace  This line

```
let fromDateBtn:UIButton = AccountOpeningButton()
```

With This:

```
let fromDateBtn = AccountOpeningButton()
```

And add this method in your class

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
```

> You can have more than one init method, but you have to obey the
>   inheritance and hierarchy rules. And you need to definitely understand
>   what are called convenience initializers.

For more details find [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: Accept the answer. (Click the check mark.) up voting is optional. Accepting the correct answer is not.