# Swift UIViewController crashing w/ (fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, initwithcoder

I have created a swift file `MainViewController` that declares/defines a class `MainViewController`.  I've set my storyboard's only scene's custom class as this class.  I have the following code:

```
import Foundation

class MainViewController : UIViewController {



   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }

   func setup() {

      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   }

}
```

When I run the project I get the following crash log:

> fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/DraWave/content/MainViewController.swift, line 17

It seems that this is an issue people have experienced before and that swift has introduced some complexities regarding view controller initialization.  I am currently learning swift but cannot resolve what the issue is.  It may be worth noting that this is a mixed-language project that contains objective-c classes.

Comment: Why not comment out fatalError? ``//fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")``

Comment: why not indeed.  because i'm tired i suppose.  to be fair though, the compiler did place that code there automatically.  what is the purpose of the fatalerror?

Comment: ``fatalError()`` is a way to print a message and stop execution unconditionally. Usually used to highlight a certain part for developer to address this issue.

Comment: i kinda meant what was the logic for it to be in the body of this particular method.

Comment: You could check a reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class/24036440#24036440

Comment: Delete the entire function.