# "Fatal Error: init(coder:) has not been implemented" error in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing the SwiftyCam pod in my iOS 10/ XCode8.2 app. It's a custom cameraviewcontroller pod, it seems really simple to use and implement, but when I run it it gives me this error. Can you guys help me? I already looked at other questions, using their lines of codes that worked for them, but nada, none of them worked for me.

Here's the code:

```
class randomController: SwiftyCamViewController, SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, CAPSPageMenuDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate   {
    private var backgroundImage: UIImage

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.backgroundImage = image
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
        backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage
        view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        let cancelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0))
        cancelButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel"), for: UIControlState())
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancel), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(cancelButton)
    }

    func cancel() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the enclosing class declaration ? That is, show the lines `class  xxx`

Comment: Remove the call to `fatalError’

Comment: @Paulw11, and he should also implement constructor too

Comment: Yes, and probably call super too.

Comment: @paper1111 edited the question with the things you asked

Comment: Appreciate the help from all of you, can you explain to me how to fix it? if i cancel fatal error, xcode tells me "self used before super.init call"

Comment: @Paulw11 can you help me understand this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class it tells you to try call super, which is what @Paulw11 was trying to say

Comment: @paper1111 already tried before, it gives me this error xcode "Property self.backgroundImage" not initialized at super.init call"

Comment: You need to either initialise `backgroundImage` in `init:coder` or declare it as an optional. I suggest you read the section in the Swift book on initialisation

Comment: I accept your suggestion, but can i ask you to make an example so i can fix this issue right away? It's driven me mad in the last 2 hours