# fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") in AACHART

Tags: swift, charts

Hello I am using this pod
https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartKit-Swift
in this pod I am using my own UIView and set class `AAChartView`
and setup in my `viewDidLoad` I am calling this function and getting error

> fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

```
func setUpAAChartView() {

    aaChartModel = AAChartModel()
        .chartType(.line)//Can be any of the chart types listed under `AAChartType`.
        .animationType(.bounce)
        .title("TITLE")//The chart title
        .subtitle("subtitle")//The chart subtitle
        .dataLabelEnabled(false) //Enable or disable the data labels. Defaults to false
        .tooltipValueSuffix("USD")//the value suffix of the chart tooltip
        .categories(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                     "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])
        .colorsTheme(["#fe117c","#ffc069","#06caf4","#7dffc0"])
        .series([
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Tokyo")
                .data([7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6])
                .toDic()!,
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("New York")
                .data([0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5])
                .toDic()!,
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Berlin")
                .data([0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0])
                .toDic()!,
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("London")
                .data([3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8])
                .toDic()!,])

    aaChartView?.aa_drawChartWithChartModel(aaChartModel!)

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036393/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initcoder-for-class

Comment: I think this error refers to your own UIView missing the method `init(coder:)`.
Can you start this view without the AAChartModel?

Comment: Do you use xibs or storyboards? If so, this class can not be instantiated from a xib or storyboard. You have to inject this view in code.

Comment: i am giving class AAchart to view from storybaord

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version AAChartKit-Swift, AAChartView is supported in XIB, you can update your AAChartKit-Swift pod version to the latest content.