# How to do UITableView style and frame in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

How to do this in Swift code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023613/programmatically-uitableview-using-swift ?

Comment: Have you done *any* research? What have you tried?

Comment: why have not you read at least the basic language syntax about _Swift_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code

```
var myTableView :UITableView =  UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
```

P.S: Probably you should take a [swift tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1).