# Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:textContainer:) when instantiating a subclass of NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to **subclass** `NSTextView` and have a **custom initializer**.

When I add a custom initializer like below:

```
init(frame: NSRect, view: NSView) {
        
    self.view = view
    self.textLayer = CATextLayer()
        
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

the compiler complains about missing `init?(coder: NSCoder)` initializer and suggests the below as a fix:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

When I apply this fix, the code compiles fine but when I run it, the app crashes giving me `Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:textContainer:)` error in the logs.

**I looked at other solutions on SOF** and they suggested the below:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

Unfortunately, the above also doesn't fix the issue and I am getting the same crash error as before.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? I am using Swift 5.0. Additionally, I know there are other similar questions on SOF but their answers didn't solve my problem (maybe because of Swift's version).

Do note that removing the custom `init` will fix the issue but I would like to keep the custom initializer in this case.

*P.S. Swift noob here so apologies if its something trivial.*

Comment: What does the custom `init` look like?

Comment: @PhillipMills updated the question with my custom `init`

Comment: Please show your real code, don't just describe it. We need to be able to copy and paste right into a project and just go. Don't make us write the code you already wrote. Thanks.

Comment: @matt I have pasted all the necessary code in the question. It's a normal class extending `NSTextView` and has one custom `init` as mentioned in the question. There's nothing else yet in the class.

Comment: Yes, but then I still have to write `class MyTextView: NSTextView` etc. Do you see? There's nothing else in the class but you didn't even _provide_ the class. So I have no way of knowing if I'm doing what you did, and you are making me do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subclass needs to call the designated initializer of the parent.
Change `super.init(frame: frame)` to `super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: nil)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that writing a new designated initializer blocks inheritance, so the real designated initializer, [`init(frame:textContainer:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449347-init), can no longer be called.

You need to make your initializer a *convenience* initializer to prevent that from happening. And then you won't be forced to write `init(coder:)` either and all will be well.

Comment: And please read my https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719434/341994 — basically, this is an unwitting duplicate of that question, as the whole phenomenon, you will see, is identical.

Comment: When I add `convenience` to `init`, it says, Convenience initializer must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init'). However, the other answer solved my problem.

Comment: Also, how does my custom `init` block inheritance? And, how is `init(frame:textContainer:)` the designated initializer?

Comment: That's right, you'd have to rewrite. But you can do that. I'm not going to bother to show you the rewrite. Your other questions are just factual, I'm not going to repeat myself.