# Not able to call tableView Delegate and DataSource methods

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've designed a `tableView` and `tableViewCell` programatically, without the use of storyboards. My `viewDidLoad()` in the `ViewController` looks something like this:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.register(TicketsTableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier)
tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: .plain)
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

And my `tableViewCell` looks something like this:

```
class TicketsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    //Other View related stuff
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

The thing is, when I run it, I'm able to see the `tableView`, but not the cells. Furthermore, when I add a breakpoint at `cellForRowAt:`, it does not get called. What is that I'm doing wrong? Is there something wrong I'm doing with the reuse identifier? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check numberOfSectionsInTableView or other delegate method call or not ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023613/programmatically-uitableview-using-swift

Comment: What is the data source?  How many elements are there?  The table requires these pieces of information.

Comment: The data source is a dictionary, even the `numberOfRowsInSection` is not getting called. @ElTomato

Comment: None of the delegate methods are getting called. @Miteshjadav

Comment: @shravan.sukumar  write your full code

Comment: did you include UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource in your UIViewController definition?

Comment: Yes. @Russell, I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is first you have set `delegate` and `datasource` of `tableView` after that you are re-initializing the `tableView` with line `tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: .plain)` so put that line first then set `delegate` and `datasource` and register cell.

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: .plain)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.register(TicketsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Couldn't believe such a small mistake I've made.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this may help for you

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
 {

var tableView : UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.setUpTableView()

}
func setUpTableView()
{
    // Create only one table view.
    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 10, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, self.view.frame.size.width - self.view.frame.size.width / 5, self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - 20), style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
//table view data source

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    return cell

  }

 }
```